# Sefirat ha'omer as Conditional mitzvah

Tags: mitzvah, mistakes, sefirat-ha-omer

Are there any other “mitzvot” besides counting S’fira that are cumulative?  In other words, if you forget a day of S’fira you can no longer count with a bracha.  Are there any other types of mitzvot that follow this pattern?  For example, if one doesn’t say Kiddush Friday night, you can still say Kiddush on Shabbat morning or the next week.  Same for benching.  If you don’t wash before a seuda you can still bench and of course not benching once does not preclude you from benching at the next meal.

This question follows the opinion that the entire of sefira is one long mitzvah, not that each day is its own discrete mitzvah. And this is not about a bracha giving me permission to do the next activity or the lack of an activity precluding my making a bracha (if I didn't eat, I don't bentch).

Comment: Also, if you miss lighting candles one night of Chanukah, you still do the rest.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/22647/759

Comment: How about the sequences that various kodshim and taharot procedures require? E.g. You can't eat the Pesach without first slaughtering it and offering it. A metzora' can't bring the final korban until the other steps of purification are complete.

Comment: @IsaacMoses I thought those are more like I can't wear my Tallit after attaching the tzitzit to one corner if I haven't attached to the other corners. But I agree this is kinda vague.

Comment: Dan, do you mean in your title 'conditional' or 'cumulative'?

Comment: The person who sent me the question to ask used "cumulative" but the logic of the question calls forth "conditional" so I left one language in the question, and another in the title. I would edit the asker's language but I felt that had an intent in his use of the word. And he's older than I am so I defer to him.

Comment: _" if one doesn’t say Kiddush Friday night, you can still say Kiddush on Shabbat morning"_ -- but which kiddush do you say Shabbat morning?

Comment: @Menachem The full Kiddush from Friday night with both brachot but without Vayechulu. http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16423/759

Comment: @Dan The example of Kiddush the next morning is a good one because it actually makesup for the Kiddush you missed, but saying Kiddush the next Shabbos is equal to saying that he could count Sefirah next year!

Comment: @Menachem but you still say a kiddush, even if the text is a "make up". By sefirah, not counting precludes the next counting. I don't say yesterday's count a day late, or count twice to make up for what I missed.

Comment: @Danno There is such an opinion out there that if you miss day 5 you say "Yesterday was 5. Today is 6."

Answer (score 2):

If a congregation did not read the Parsha (portion) of the Torah one Shabbos they read that Parsha the next Shabbos, but if the Shabbos they didn't read (or the next Shabbos) was a double Parsha or the next Shabbos was a new Chumash (e.g. they didn't read Vayichee) then there is a disagreement whether they should make up for the missed Parshiyos. See SA OC 135:2 and Mishnah Berurah #7.

Another Mitzvah would be Nezirus - if the Nazir became Tomei Meis he did not fulfill his Nezirus days and he has to start counting all over again.

Also Shofar blowing, if one messed up during Tekios (let's say he did Tekiah Teruah Shivorim) he had to go back to the beginning of that Tekiah.

Comment: but by both nezirus and shofar, one can go back and start again. By sefirah, you can't.

Comment: That is because by Sefirah one can't physically bring that day back (because it depends on 2nd day of Pesach), for Shofar that would be equal to one who made those errors immediately before Yom Tov went out - so he can't make up for them any more. For a Nezirus there is also such an example if he turned 120 (euphemism) before he managed to restart the Nezirus. In both cases the shofar sounds that he did blow and the original days that he kept as a Nazir are not counted even as part of a full Mitzvah (maybe for the Nazir there's some reward for those days he kept Kehalacha but by Shofar, no